# why findFragmentById return always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I can not understand this problem. This line always returns null and this makes the app crash. The line is:

```
FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) 
manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));
```

fragment is null. To better understand the situation. I have this two activity

the first is P2P Activity

```
package it.linup.maint.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.*;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg.R;



public class P2P  extends Activity implements ChannelListener, 
DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener {

public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
private WifiP2pManager manager;
private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
private boolean retryChannel = false;

private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

/**
 * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
 */
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // add necessary intent values to be matched.

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);

intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

}

/** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

/**
 * Remove all peers and clear all fields. This is called on
 * BroadcastReceiver receiving a state change event.
 */
public void resetData() {
    DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
    DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        fragmentList.clearPeers();
    }
    if (fragmentDetails != null) {
        fragmentDetails.resetViews();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_items, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.atn_direct_enable:
            if (manager != null && channel != null) {

                // Since this is the system wireless settings activity, it's
                // not going to send us a result. We will be notified by
                // WiFiDeviceBroadcastReceiver instead.

                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            } else {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "channel or manager is null");
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.atn_direct_discover:
            if (!isWifiP2pEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(P2P.this, R.string.p2p_off_warning,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.onInitiateDiscovery();
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(P2P.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(P2P.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.showDetails(device);

}

@Override
public void connect(WifiP2pConfig config) {
    manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver will notify us. Ignore for now.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(P2P.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    final DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
    fragment.resetViews();
    manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            fragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onChannelDisconnected() {
    // we will try once more
    if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        resetData();
        retryChannel = true;
        manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelDisconnect() {

    /*
     * A cancel abort request by user. Disconnect i.e. removeGroup if
     * already connected. Else, request WifiP2pManager to abort the ongoing
     * request
     */
    if (manager != null) {
        final DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        if (fragment.getDevice() == null
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.CONNECTED) {
            disconnect();
        } else if (fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.AVAILABLE
                || fragment.getDevice().status == WifiP2pDevice.INVITED) {

            manager.cancelConnect(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(P2P.this, "Aborting connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(P2P.this,
                            "Connect abort request failed. Reason Code: " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

  }
}
```

the second activy is a BroadcastReceiver and this were the error is

WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver

```
package it.linup.maint.activity;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;


import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg.R;



public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiP2pManager manager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
private P2P activity;

/**
 * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
 * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
 * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
 */
public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                   P2P activity) {
    super();
    this.manager = manager;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.activity = activity;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
 * android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
            activity.resetData();

        }
        android.util.Log.d(P2P.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
        // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
        // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.requestPeers(channel, (WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
        }
        android.util.Log.d(P2P.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            // we are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP

            DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                    .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
            manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
        } else {
            // It's a disconnect
            activity.resetData();
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();

        DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

    }
 }
}
```

The P2P Activity is called inside a tabhost activity

Main Activity

```
package it.linup.maint.activity;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg.R;


public class Main extends TabActivity
{




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Log");
    //TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Debug");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("P2P");




    // Set the Tab name and Activity
    // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
    tab1.setIndicator("Home");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class));

    tab2.setIndicator("Log");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, Log.class));

    //tab3.setIndicator("Debug");
    //tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, DebugActivity.class));

    tab4.setIndicator("P2P");
    tab4.setContent(new Intent(this, P2P.class));







    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab4);
    //tabHost.addTab(tab3);



    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
   // tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

public void setText(String text)
{
    Log activity = (Log) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("Log");
    activity.refreshContent(text);
}

public FFmpeg getFfmpeg()
{
    Home home = (Home ) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("Home");
    return home.getFfmpeg();
 }


}
```

the log of the error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg, PID: 25845
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in it.linup.maint.activity.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver@86b515
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:979)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.linup.maint.activity.DeviceListFragment.updateThisDevice(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice)' on a null object reference
                  at it.linup.maint.activity.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java:94)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:969)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
```

i can't understand why i get this error.

Comment: `second activy is a BroadcastReceiver` `Activity` is definitely not a `BroadcastReceiver`. Also I can't see you adding a fragment with your ID. That is the reason that you don't find it by id - you don't tell the system that it has that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add your add your fragment with a ID during fragment transactions, either add by id or tag then you can find by id or tag. Thats is the reason it cant find your fragment thus returning null causing the exception.

Comment: ok.. i'm very stupid... i setted the wrong resourse with setContentView(R.layout.main); thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because you didn't add any fragment with that id. Your manager doesn't create your fragment, you have to tell him which fragment has that id.